# How to avoid adding more than one tap gesture to any cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a weird problem. When scrolling down, cells disappear if Tap Gesture happened.

Looks like I need to stop adding Tap Gesture to cells. I've done testing of this condition in function but it didn't work.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as!  ToDoItemsCell

...

        cell.textField.delegate = self
        cell.textField.isHidden = true
        cell.toDoItemLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(toDoItemLabelTapped))

        tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        cell.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

        return cell
}
```

And here is my function:

```
 @objc func toDoItemLabelTapped(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        if gesture.state == .ended {

            let location = gesture.location(in: self.tableView)

             if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: location) {

                if let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? ToDoItemsCell {
                cell.toDoItemLabel.isHidden = true
                cell.textField.isHidden = false
                cell.textField.becomeFirstResponder()
                cell.textField.text = cell.toDoItemLabel.text

           }
         }
       }
     }
```

Tapping works, but it keeps adding to other cells and makes them disappear. What can be the issue?

Comment: Why add a tap gesture at all? Why not simply implement the `didSelectRowAt`?

Comment: And your problem isn't really with the tap gesture. It's that you don't properly keep track of the state of each row and properly set the text field state in `cellForRowAt`.

Comment: @rmaddy I can't use `didSelectRowAt` as I need to tap a Label inside the cell, also I'll have later an image to tap in cell.

Did I get you correctly that I need to add IF closure to check state of text field in `cellForRowAt`? Like `if cell.textField.isHidden == false {` and adding gesture comes?

Comment: Then why are you adding the tap gesture to the entire cell and not just the label?

Comment: No, you need to set `cell.textField.isHidden` based on the current state you have stored in your data model (which needs to be updated in your gesture handler).

Answer (score 0):

Gesture should be added once to each cell. In your code gesture will be added every time **cellForRowAt** will be called and it will be called many times especially when you scroll down to list.

Move you gesture add code to ToDoItemsCell class and than you can use delegates to inform your view controller when cell gets tapped.

```
protocol ToDoItemsCellDelegate {
    toDoItemsCellDidTapped(_ cell: ToDoItemsCell)
}

class ToDoItemsCell : UITableViewCell {
    weak var delegate: ToDoItemsCellDelegate?
    var indexPath: IndexPath!
    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        // code common to all your cells goes here
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(toDoItemLabelTapped))

        tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        self.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }

    @objc func toDoItemLabelTapped(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
         delegate?.toDoItemsCellDidTapped(self)
    }
}
```

In function **cellForRowAt** you can just select the delegate and set indexPath.

**Note:**
If you just wanted to perform action when user taps any cell you can use **didSelectRowAt** method of UITableViewDelegate.

Comment: While this is a good approach it doesn't actually address the issue with the code in the OP.